# Default cell values when editing new row non-programmatically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I maintain manually, whenever a new line is edited I would like the columns in the row to have a default value, such as True or False or some other category value.

[image]

I know about using e.g. =B2:B if another column has a formula referencing B but I am just talking about setting a default value per cell. Is there a smart way of achieving this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example output

Comment: Does this example of file above help explain? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hIDfupO1mbFVl_x1_8741qltF2MpBJ43QxRZ1UqB53I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: sorry, fixed that

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this formula:

```
=IF(LEN($A2)<>0,"Yes","-")
```

or

```
=IF(LEN($A2)<>0,"No","-")
```

But you may need to drag-down the formula manually if you will use this. That is why I decided to set the cell value to "-" if ever column A is empty so that you will be aware until which row did you copied the formula.

Sample Sheet:
[image]

Comment: Works great for me, can replace yes with whatever category I want, makes adding a new record for this project a breeze as a majority go with the defaults, dragging down non-issue, thanks Ron!

Answer (score 1):

see:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,{"yes", "no", "no", "yes"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I get errors: Error Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B4...this is when B4 is empty

Comment: I also tried this one before and this will not work if you aim to modify the default values manually on a specific cells. It will prevent the arrayformula() to expand its results.